# Did someone happen to see maven archetype for Grails+GWT project?

Tags: gwt, grails, maven, maven-archetype

Did someone happen to see maven archetype for Grails+GWT project?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you'll have to create your own with ideally your corporate Maven repository. Not convenient, but not "challenging" either.